# How to access class instance method using Interface ref type?

Tags: java, interface

Have a below code snippet.

```
public class Character {
    private static String type;
    
    public void doMainSomething() {
        System.out.println("Doing Main Something");
    }
    
    public static class Gorgon extends Character implements Monster {
        
        public int level;
        
        @Override
        public int getLevel() { return level; }

        public Gorgon() {
            Character.type = "Gorgon";
        }
        
        public void doSomething() {
            System.out.println("Doing Something");
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Character.Gorgon gor = new Character.Gorgon();
        Monster mon = new Character.Gorgon();
        mon.doSomething();  -> Error
    
        
    }
}
```

How can I access inner class's `Gorgon` method `doSomething` using `mon` ? Is there any specific way, so that we could access class's method using Interface's ref type ?

Comment: I suggest your to extract Gorgon to a new type using your IDE... That will be easier to maintain hereafter.

Answer (score 1):

Proper way is to declare the `doSomething()` method on `Monster` interface. If a method needs to be called on interface type, then that method needs to be on the interface or it's parent.

If that is not doable, then you can safely cast the `mon` to `Character.Gorgon`

```
 if  (mon instanceof Character.Gorgon) {
       ((Character.Gorgon) mon).doSomething();
 }
```

Comment: any other way I could access doSomething without cast and not adding into interface ?

Comment: If I were you I would not go about fishing for other ways. I would rather try to redesign the architecture. Casting is the most sane way for your scenario.